Layer stack up and impedance matching- 100 ohm
I have a 14 layer stack up as follows (the stack up is from EURO circuit):

I need to provide 100 Ohm differential impedance for my LVDS on layer 7, currently by the information from the manufacturer (Prepreg thickness , dielectric,...) I can get 91,55 ohm for differential pair :

I noticed there is a drop down menu in each layer, that I can choose an top reference for the current layer. If I change the reference for layer 7 to GND3 as follow, the differential impedance changes from 91.55 ohm changes to 98.6 ohm:

Final impedance calculation:

My question is if we change this top reference, do this impedance really change? or in really I will get 91.55 ohm?
Regards,

You have an asymmetric differential stripline which will have both GND3 and GND4 as reference planes, but GND3 will dominate. The Saturn PCB toolkit has a calculator for this. Although it will give you an answer, I have never had the same stack, track and gap from any two PCB vendors for controlled impedance.

RE " If I change the reference for layer 7 to GND3 as follow,", you do realize that to do this, you must remove all copper from layers 4, 5, and 6 in the areas around your stripline, right?

@ The Photon thanks for the useful answer, would you please let me know do you means copper (track)? if yes, yes we are ware of this and concern about how much space do we need to keep employ below?

@ The Photon you answered my question, maybe would you please shard it as an answer not an comment?


My question is if we change this top reference, do this impedance
really change? or in really I will get 91.55 ohm?

I'm going to ask you to consider a better and more relevant question i.e. if the terminating impedance does change to 90 Ω how will this affect the operation of your circuit?
Consider a 1 metre length of 100 Ω cable terminated in 99 Ω with a frequency of 1 MHz: -

That doesn't look problematic in terms of the received blue signal. But, that shouldn't be a surprise because it's a very minor impedance mismatch. What if the termination is 90 Ω: -

I don't think it's problematic either but, if we were transmitting a 10 MHz square wave into a 90 Ω termination and, we focussed on one cycle: -

You can see that there is a more serious degradation of the signal but, is it really going to upset things that much?
This is my preferred way of looking at it i.e. don't get fixated on specmanship but instead, focus on what effect it might produce.

Establish what distance the signal has to travel over
Establish the highest frequency
Run a simulation
Analyse the results
Make a judgement


@ Andy aka thank you for the accurate answer, our working frequency would be 500MHz to 1GHZ for LVDS.

Let me try and be clear here. You need to take the next step and use a simulation tool. That's my advice @Andromeda

@Andromeda if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

@Andromeda I think I've answered your question given the details you have provided. You should easily be able to simulate this with free software like I have done above. Micro-cap free download
